# Find a recursive algorithm to find $a^{2^n}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recursive-algorithms, recursion

Edit1: Used Latex. =]
Edit2: Thanks for the guidance to the users below. Really helped me out editing the post and guidance on the math problem.

The question gave me a hint: $a^{2^{n+1}}  = (a^{2^n}) ^ 2 $

This one is a lot harder than the ones given in the examples...

Comments:
At first I thought the hint said $a^{2^{n+1}}$ = $(a^{2^{n}})$ * $1^{2}$ but it does not seem to be the case.

My approach:
I tried leveraging the hint by solving it in terms of $a^{2^{n}} $ which would mean
$a^{2{^n}}$ = $a^{2^{n+1}}$ / $(1)^2$. But it does not look right.

What I know from reading the textbook: If I can find what $a^{2^n}$ represents, writing the recursive definition will be a lot easier.

Comment: Please put some more brackets in your question, otherwise nobody has any idea whether you are asking about $(a^2)^n$ or $a^{(2^n)}$.

Comment: How come you still didn't learn how to use Latex?

Comment: @David it is the second option.

Comment: Don't put that in the comments, edit your question.

Comment: Thanks @mathguy, just what I was about to say myself!  Nicholas, I've edited the title, now you can do the rest.

Comment: @Nicholas If you want to use latex, wrap text in \$[latexcode]\$

Comment: The correct statement is $a^{2^{n+1}}=(a^{2^n})^2$.

Comment: You are not reading the hint correctly.  The $2$ is squaring the $a^{2^n}$

Comment: I have edited the question for our benefit. But at 83 or so rep, I hope that Nicholas can learn to Tex.

Comment: @RossMillikan Wow...you are right.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the sequence $a,a^2,a^{4},a^8,\cdots$ - what do we do to go from one term to the next?

Comment: To get the following term, multiply the current term by itself.

Comment: In other words, square it.

Comment: Well that would mean $a^{2{^n}}$ = ($a^{2^{n-1}}) {^ 2} $

Comment: Yes, that equation is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. It really got me to think more critically.